# PHP max_execution_time with includes

Tags: php

Just wandering how the `max_execution_time` works.
The documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) states that the option sets:

> the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run

How does this work for includes/requires?

Example:

```
file1.php
<?php
  include("file2.php");
  include("file3.php");
?>

file2.php
<?php
  //some script that takes 6 minutes
?>

file3.php
<?php
  echo "hello"
?>
```

If file2.php takes 6 minutes (and the max_execution_time is set to 5 minutes), does control pass back to file1.php and continue running, or does the whole file quit?

Answer (score 1):

The execution breaks and throw a error.

Answer (score 1):

Max execution time is the time your script can be executed. No matter how many includes do you have. So if if at any point of time the script will run out of time, everything will stop and you will receive

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of XX seconds exceeded